# Fedora 32 unable to unpack cpio.zstd rpm

Tags: fedora, rpm

I am trying to build rpm under fedora 32. Spec file doesn't contains any special macros, just standard configure, make, make install. I found that under fedora 32 rpmbuild command pack rpm content to the .cpio.zstd archive, that can't be installed later.
`dnf install` command for this rpm dies with error:

```
Error unpacking rpm package ffmpeg-1:4.3-1.fc32.x86_64
```

Same spec file under FC31 or EL8 produces valid rpm.

So, my question - what I am doing wrong? How to build standard cpio rpm under FC32, that can be installed?

Answer (score 1):

This is cause by new compression introduced in Fedora 32. Older distribution does not understand this new compression.

You have to use the tool which is intended to build packages for different version of Fedoras/RHEL:

```
mock -r fedora-31-x86_64 ffmpeg.src.rpm
```

or

```
mock -r epel-8-x86_64 ffmpeg.src.rpm
```

For more info see https://github.com/rpm-software-management/mock/wiki

Comment: Thank you for reply, I am wondered, why I am unable to install rpm, that was built on the same os. Do you know, how to build it using standard buildrpm command?

Comment: You should be able to install on F32 package which you built on F32. But you will not be able to install package on EL8 or F31 which you built on F32.

Comment: This is exactly the problem, I am unable to install FC32 -> FC32.